# Using an enum from another file as a parameter in PHP

Tags: php, enums

I have a php file that handles mailing. The Mail() function requires a case to determine the subject and body of the email that is to be sent. To prevent the caller from giving wrong parameters I am using an enum as shown below:

```
<?php

enum MailCase
{
    case bestOffer;
    case notForSale;
}

function Email($product_ean, MailCase $case)
{
    // TODO: Product titel in onderwerp.
    $to = 'receiver@company.com';
    $headers = 'From: sender@company.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: sender@company.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    switch ($case) {
        case MailCase::bestOffer:
            $subject = 'Lorem ipsum 1';
            $message = '
            This body is variant 1 for case 1.
            PRODUCT: ' . $product_ean;
            break;
        case MailCase::notForSale:
            $subject = 'Lorem ipsum 2';
            $message = '
            This body is variant 2 for case 2.
            PRODUCT: ' . $product_ean;
            break;
    }
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

This php file is required in the main file and is called via `require_once("mailer.php");`

Then, the following function calls the function that starts the mail procedure:

```
alertRetailer($product, MailCase::notForSale);
```

Which executes this:

```
function alertRetailer($product, MailCase $case)
{
    Email($product, $case);
}
```

When running this program the following parse error is show in the browser:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'MailCase' (T_STRING) in /domain/mailer.php on line 3
```

As far as I can see the file that provides the mailing functionality and the enum is required the right way and IntelliSense doesn't show an error that the file is not found. I would like to hear you guys' view on my scenario.

EDIT:

PHP version was checked:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you import that `MailCase` enum properly? Why not put it into an external file to properly use autoloading?

Comment: This is the error message you'll get if you're using a version of PHP that doesn't support enums. It's clearly reading the right file, else it couldn't report the line number.

Comment: @NicoHaase I am fairly new to PHP and not familiar with autoloading. Shouldn't require_once work in this situation? It does for other files. All the required files are located in the same folder inside the directory.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have checked my PHP version: 8.1. Should be the right one, right?

Comment: It's possible to have multiple versions installed. You might have 8.0 or earlier for CLI and 8.1 for FPM. Run `php -v` from the command line.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Also just checked CLI and its on 8.1.12

Comment: That "PHP Language Level" is the IDE's setting about what to expect, not what's actually installed. You clearly don't have 8.1 in the context that the script is running. Try adding `phpinfo();exit;` to the top of mailer.php, you prob have 8.0 in FPM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250974/discussion-between-luuc-and-alex-howansky).